# Migration to XE5 without making change in Delphi 7 datatypes

Tags: delphi, migrate

I am using Delphi 7 and I love it due to small exe size, and no worries about 64bit datatypes as I really don't need it.

Now as WinXP is dead, and Win7 is also in its last stage, I really see a need to migrate to newer version of Delphi, and have XE3 installed now. My source code uses Pointer(s), String(s) (not AnsiString), DWORD, Cardinal etc. I don't want to make my code 64bit compatible as I really don't need it.

As far as I know, 32bit codes can run fine on 64bit OS, and I just want to confirm that is there any option in XE5 to compile exe like I did in Delphi7, no need to worry about OS Architecture, as Delhi 7 compiler always compiled 32bit exe, and datatypes are always 32bit regardless of System Architecture.

So, in short, **I just need to upgrade my IDE, not the source, not the support for another CPU architecture.** Just plain 32bit application, which can run in both 32bit and 64bit environment. Is it possible?

Regards,

Comment: Is what possible, exactly?  You say you already have XE3 installed, and most D7 code will compile in it and XE5 without modification, so what are you asking?

Comment: Well, you'll have to deal with Unicode strings probably. And the executable size will be jigger but then you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: @MartynA I know most D7 will compile just fine, but what about datatypes on runtime? Like i : Integer compiled as 32bit exe, and run on 32bit system, will have 4 byte size, but what if that 32bit exe is run on 64bit system?
Will it remain 4byte or will change to 8byte?

Comment: Why would a 32bit exe suddenly change its data sizes just because it's run on a 64bit system?  If that happened it would break every existing 32bit exe run on 64bit Windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes Bro, I think changing my string declaration to AnsiString can make it safe.
But what I am concerned for is already posted as comment to MartynA

Comment: @MartynA
Aha, that means Integer, WORD, DWORD will behave same like they did in Delhi 7 if I compile only 32bit exe.
Thanks, I will try and update here.
Just another doubt, will changing my String declarations to AnsiString will be good enough to avoid any issue with string manipulation?

Comment: If you treat strings purely as an "opaque" datatype with no attempt to manipulate them at the byte-level (i.e. how they are represented im-memory), you should be able to leave your string declarations as-is.  Suck it 'n see ...

Comment: Changing `string` to `AnsiString` won't give identical behaviour for all code because `AnsiString` is now code page aware. Frankly, if you don't want to change your code you may be better off sticking with Delphi 7.